# django templates - passing variables between templates

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have one template that includes a popup page. I loop through all values in a list that I get from the view and want to include information from each element of the list in the popup.

page1.html:

```
{% include "popup.html" %}
...
{% for element in someList %}
    <div class="col s3 some-button"><a onclick="$(showPopup('popup'));">More Info</a></div>
{% endfor %}
```

showPopup is a Javascript function that will show the popup.

In popup.html I reference `element` from the for loop above:

popup.html

```
...
{{ element }} 
...
```

But the popup.html template does not seem to be able to find the `element` from the for loop, since nothing is shown. Is there a way to make it so the popup.html is able to reference `element`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found using this worked for my purposes:

page1.html:

```
...
{% for element in someList %}
    {% include "popup.html" with element=element %}
    <div class="col s3 some-button"><a onclick="$(showPopup('popup'));">More Info</a></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your link you can add an attribute `data-element="{{ element }}"` and in the `onclick` method associated with the link you can retrieve the value like this:

```
var el = $(this).data("element");
```

Now, pass `el` to your popup.